# Error: polifill promise angularfire2

Tags: angularfire2

I'm stuck with my angular fire-2 offline/ionic3 app. it keeps giving me this error when I try to upload my app to ionic view. it has no errors when I build for Android nor when I use ionic lab.

I saw that other people have a polyfill problem and they suggest doing:

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```

but it does not work for me, the error is still there. these are my versions (package.json):

"firebase": "^4.3.0",
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
"angularfire2-offline": "^4.2.4",

```
     Error: ./node_modules/firebase/utils/promise.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill' in
remote:             '/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/utils' resolve 'promise-polyfill' in
remote:             '/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/utils' Parsed request is a module using description file:
remote:             /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/package.json (relative path: ./utils) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
remote:             valid alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/package.json
remote:             (relative path: ./utils) resolve as module looking for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using
remote:             description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain
remote:             a valid alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path:
remote:             ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path:
remote:             ./node_modules/promise-polyfill) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:             /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
remote:             configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't
remote:             contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js doesn't exist .json Field
remote:             'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json
remote:             doesn't exist as directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill doesn't exist
remote:             [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts]
remote:             [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json]
remote:             [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill] @ ./node_modules/firebase/utils/promise.js 14:76-103 @
remote:             ./node_modules/firebase/app/firebase_app.js @ ./node_modules/firebase/app.js @
remote:             ./node_modules/firebase/firebase-browser.js @ ./src/providers/camera/camera.ts @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @
remote:             ./src/app/main.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install angularfire2 firebase promise-polyfill --save

angularfire2 has updated their docs.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic3-Angular4.md

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same error after installing angularfire2 to my app; only when pushing the code to ionic pro platform.
First I had the error building for ios as well, that got away by updating angularfire2 to another version :

```
npm i --save angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1
```

Maybe you can try that ?